# how to copy file with specific name available in list from one folder to other folder pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have many files in folder , i want to copy files from folder to other folder if file name is available in list .

```
Filenamelist=['212','98901','8098']

input folder=['212','98901','8098','66780','789']

output=['212','98901','8098']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileNameList=['212','98901','8098']

inputFolder=['212','98901','8098','66780','789']

toOutput = []

for name in fileNameList:
    if name in inputFolder:
        toOutput.append(name)
```

will give you

```
['212', '98901', '8098']
```